# How to unit test my own implementation of EventSource

Tags: unit-testing, etw, etw-eventsource

I'm using System.Diagnostics.EventSource for semantic logging (.net 4.5).

I would like to create proper unit tests to make sure that the events were actually fired with the appropriate content.

How can I do that?

Example of method to test:

```
[Event(ExceptionOccuredId, Message = "An {0} occured: {1} Stacktrace: {2}{3}", Keywords = Keywords.Exception, Level = EventLevel.Error)]
internal void ExceptionOccured(string typeName, string message, string stackTrace, string relatedMessages)
{
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     if (relatedMessages.Any())
     {
          sb.Append(string.Format(" Additional messages: {0}"));
     }

     this.WriteEvent(ExceptionOccuredId, typeName, message, stackTrace, sb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Use EventListener (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventlistener%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)and listen to your Events and look if they are ok.

Comment: have you tried this? Does it work?